# How to direct flows to specific vf queue?

Tags: nic, ethtool, sr-iov

[SR-IOV](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-3196/glbzi.html) allows us to create a VF from PF, now I want to direct some flows to VF via Flow Director.

Here is `ethtool` help message

```
action N
    Specifies the Rx queue to send packets to, or some other action.
    loc N
    Specify the location/ID to insert the rule. This will overwrite any rule present in that location and will not go through any of the rule ordering process.

    delete N
    Deletes the RX classification rule with the given ID.
```

I'm really confused about how to set the value of `action` so that the flow matching filters can be directed to specific VF.

Comment: it depends upon NIC and ASIC version. what is NIC details and firmware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in [DPDK Flow Bifurcation How-to Guide](https://dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/v17.11/howto/flow_bifurcation.html) (Yes, the answer is not in `SR-IOV` docs or `Ethtool` docs, orz)

example:

```
ethtool -N eth1 flow-type udp4 src-ip 192.0.2.2 dst-ip 198.51.100.2 \
        action $queue_index_in_VF0
ethtool -N eth1 flow-type udp4 src-ip 198.51.100.2 dst-ip 192.0.2.2 \
        action $queue_index_in_VF1
```

Where:

`$queue_index_in_VFn`: Bits 39:32 of the variable defines VF id + 1; the lower 32 bits indicates the queue index of the VF. Thus:

- `$queue_index_in_VF0 = (0x1 & 0xFF) << 32 + [queue index]`.
- `$queue_index_in_VF1 = (0x2 & 0xFF) << 32 + [queue index]`.

[action value structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmbJ4.png)